# Property 'getWeek' does not exist on type 'Date' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to calculate start date and end date of a week from the given date range.

Below code gives me this error `[ts] Property 'getWeek' does not exist on type 'Date'.`

```
  Date.prototype.getWeek = function(start)
{
    start = start || 0;
    var today = new Date(this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = today.getDay() - start;
    var date = today.getDate() - day;

    var StartDate = new Date(today.setDate(date));
    var EndDate = new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));
    return [StartDate, EndDate];
}

var Dates = new Date().getWeek();
```

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle and it works?

Comment: Typescript has its definitions for all primitive objects. So when you add properties to prototype, you need to also update its index.d.ts file

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0f6wnvgn/1/

Comment: It works in console for me too. (chrome)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to declare the method on the `Date` interface using interface merging

```
declare global {
    interface Date {
        getWeek (start?: number) : [Date, Date]
    }
}
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(start)
{
    start = start || 0;
    var today = new Date(this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = today.getDay() - start;
    var date = today.getDate() - day;

    var StartDate = new Date(today.setDate(date));
    var EndDate = new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));
    return [StartDate, EndDate];
}

var Dates = new Date().getWeek();
```

Or if you are not using modules:

```
interface Date {
    getWeek (start?: number) : [Date, Date]
}
```

Comment: If this helps anyone, I had to add `export { };` at the top of my file to allow this to work. I'm no TS expert by any stretch, so cannot comment on why that was needed.

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is declared as a known interface by TypeScript. `getWeek` is not a property of `Date` a so it won't let you get or modify it.

You must augment the `Date` interface:

Add a new `global.d.ts` file. In it:

```
interface Date {
    getWeek: (start: number | undefined) => [Date, Date];
}
```

Then, TypeScript will mix both declarations, and so it will recognise the existence of `getWeek` and you can define it in your code (another file, as declaration files can't contain statements)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how typescript handles extensions. You can fix your issue by modifying the interface of `Date` like this:

```
interface Date {
    getWeek(start): Array<Date>;
}
```

---

```
  Date.prototype.getWeek = function(start)
{
    start = start || 0;
    var today = new Date(this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = today.getDay() - start;
    var date = today.getDate() - day;

    var StartDate = new Date(today.setDate(date));
    var EndDate = new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));
    return [StartDate, EndDate];
}

var Dates = new Date().getWeek();
```