# Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'number | Date'

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

```
class SW {
    private startTime: number | Date
    private endTime: number | Date

    constructor() {
        this.startTime = 0,
        this.endTime = 0
    }
    start() {
        this.startTime = new Date();    
    }
    stop() {
        this.endTime = new Date();   
    }

    getDuration() {
        const seconds = (this.endTime.getTime() - this.startTime.getTime()) / 1000;
    }
}
```

Now I have this error: `Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'number | Date'.`

Based on this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875629/property-getweek-does-not-exist-on-type-date-in-typescript) I also tried to declare Date but didn't work.

```
interface Date {
    getTime(): number
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend consistently using semicolons, or relying on automatic semicolon insertion, but not a mix of the two.

Comment: thanks, I will follow that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your property is declared as `number | Date`, meaning it could be either. In your constructor, it's a number. Later, when you call `start`, you change it from `number` to `Date`. In `getDuration`, TypeScript has no way of knowing what it is (`number` or `Date`).

From looking at your code, you may want to always use `number` by using `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()` and then not using `getTime`:

```typescript
class SW {
    private startTime: number;
    private endTime: number;

    constructor() {
        this.startTime = 0,
        this.endTime = 0
    }
    start() {
        this.startTime = Date.now();    
    }
    stop() {
        this.endTime = Date.now();   
    }

    getDuration() {
        const seconds = (this.endTime - this.startTime) / 1000;
    }
}
```

You might also consider having `getDuration` either throw an error or return `NaN` when `this.endTime` or `this.startTime` is `0`.

Comment: @Sadeghbayan FWIW you can remove the need for the explicit constructor if you use [class field initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations).

Comment: didn't understand it quietly @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @Sadeghbayan - He means that if you add `= 0` to your field declarations (`private startTime: number = 0;`, you don't need to write the constructor at all. If you do that, you can also leave off the type, because TypeScript will infer `number` from the initializer: `prvate startTime = 0;`. [In context](https://pastebin.com/9VBsfr7z).

Answer (score 1):

**Just make it simple**

```
class SW {
  private startTime: number;
  private endTime: number;
 
  start() {
    this.startTime = new Date().getTime(); 
  }
  stop() {
    this.endTime = new Date().getTime();
  }

  getDuration() {
    return (this.endTime - this.startTime) / 1000;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ Vasim - FYI, [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) gives you the same value `new Date().getTime()` does, but more concisely and without an extra object allocation.